# Prevent user navigating into MaskedTextBox's Mask

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

If I have a MaskedTextBox with a US ZIP code mask (00000-9999), is there an easy way to force the mask to be filled in left to right?

For example, with a MaskedTextBox straight out of the Visual Studio toolbox, a user can click into it at any position, and the caret is placed at that position (or the end of the mask, if clicked past it). I don't see this as very user friendly... Since it essentially forces the user to then navigate to the start of the mask manually.

I've tried implementing a `MouseClick` event, but this still allows arrow key navigation (with Shift and Ctrl modifiers) as well as the End key into the mask. Then I tried implementing both a `KeyDown`/`PreviewKeyDown` combination and overriding `ProcessCmdKey` for combinations of Shift, Ctrl, arrow keys, End, etc. and those both seem "hacky" at times and pretty unwieldy.

With how useful MaskedTextBoxes can be, it's really surprising to me how not very user friendly they are out of the box... Is there a way to achieve this behavior that I'm overlooking?

**To clarify**: I *do not* want to stop the user from clicking into and navigating within information they have already entered. I just do not want the cursor to move outside of where the next input char (digit) should go (so if the current input is `"123  -    "` the caret should not be allowed further right than immediately right of the 3, but may be placed anywhere to the left of that).

Comment: Being able to jump in at any point and edit is fairly standard Windows behaviour. I can't think of anything you'd achieve by forcing them to enter left to right

Comment: @DiskJunky - Sure, I can see that being extremely useful if there is content. That I would want to say the same. But if a user were to enter a ZIP in a completely empty control, it's more work for them to need to navigate to the start (either focusing the click at the beginning or arrowing backwards). I can't think of a realistic scenario where a user would want to start entering a ZIP mid-mask.

Comment: I would use a click event and add this inside of it.

`this.yourtextbox.Select(0, 0);`

Disabling arrow key navigation is not very user-friendly in my opinion.

Comment: @AGrammerPro - Read the question. Already did that. And that does not prevent navigating in to the mask (which admittedly is not as big of a deal, but still). And I do not want to disable arrow keys completely! Just from moving past the content into empty mask.

Comment: In the `OnFocus` event you could set the position to the start after first checking to see if there's no previously filled value